# Unable to load shared library 'libdl' in dotnet2.1 running on linux container

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, system.drawing

I have a dotnet2.1 api running on Linux container (Debian Stretch) that is handling images, so it has a reference to `System.Drawing`. In dockerfile I have included as a last step the installation of native dependencies:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libc6-dev \
        libgdiplus \
        libx11-dev \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

But then at runtime I got:

> Unable to load shared library 'libdl' or one of its dependencies

A quick search on the container shows the library as installed:

```
find . -name "libdl*"
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
```

Any hint about how to fix this issue?

Edit: This is my full dockerfile content

```
FROM docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:2.1.6-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:2.1.500-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "SomeProject.Api/SomeProject.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/SomeProject.Api
RUN dotnet build "SomeProject.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
# run tests on docker build
RUN dotnet test

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SomeProject.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

# soft link
RUN ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so

# install System.Drawing native dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libc6-dev \
        libgdiplus \
        libx11-dev \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SomeProject.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile? Besides, here is a [similar thread](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/618) about using the `system.Drawing` in Asp.net core, you could check it and try to modify your code as below: `RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libgdiplus \
      #  libc6-dev \
      #  libx11-dev \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I have added the full dockerfile content. It seems like for some reason, the apt-get install is not working, because if I run it manually in the container cli it install a bunch of software and the issue is gone., however, there are no error on the image build process Tried created a soft link as per your link,  no success so far :-(

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you should be aware of this: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2848. Since your `FROM` instructions are referencing the .NET image tags from the Docker Hub registry instead of Microsoft Container Registry, you'll be affected by this deprecation of these tags.